# zip file with fat format (on linux)

Tags: zip, fat

I am trying to import contacts from micro-SD to (non Android) Nokia phone. So I first exported current contacts on micro-SD card in hope that i will be able to modify the exported file and then import it.

Exported file type is Nokia backup file `.NBF`. it seem it is actually an ordinary `zip` file.

I can unzip exported `.NBF` file and modify it (contacts are stored in `.vcf - vcard`).

However when I zip it and try to import it the phone says file is corrupted.

i checked zip files with `zipinfo`:

Unmodified file:

```
$ zipinfo Backup001.NBF
Archive:  Backup001.NBF
Zip file size: 3031 bytes, number of entries: 10
-rw-a--     0.0 fat     1160 b- stor 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/predefisasettings/usersettings/user_settings.wbxml
dr-x-hs     0.0 fat        0 b- stor 10-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder/predefisasettings/usersettings
dr-xahs     0.0 fat        0 b- stor 07-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder/predefisasettings
dr-xahs     0.0 fat        0 b- stor 07-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder
-rw-a--     0.0 fat      214 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/F01
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 10-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder/backup
-rw-a--     0.0 fat      256 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32/contacts/1.vcf
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32/contacts
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32
10 files, 1630 bytes uncompressed, 1409 bytes compressed:  13.6%
```

then i modify `1.vcf` and update `Backup001.NBF` with:

`zip Backup001.NBF -f -r predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32/contacts/1.vcf`

Modified:

```
$ zipinfo Backup001.NBF
Archive:  Backup001.NBF
Zip file size: 2958 bytes, number of entries: 10
-rw-a--     0.0 fat     1160 b- stor 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/predefisasettings/usersettings/user_settings.wbxml
dr-x-hs     0.0 fat        0 b- stor 10-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder/predefisasettings/usersettings
dr-xahs     0.0 fat        0 b- stor 07-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder/predefisasettings
dr-xahs     0.0 fat        0 b- stor 07-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder
-rw-a--     0.0 fat      214 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/F01
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 10-Jan-01 00:00 predefhiddenfolder/backup
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx      208 tx defN 20-Apr-03 01:04 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32/contacts/1.vcf
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32/contacts
drwxa--     0.0 fat        0 b- defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32
10 files, 1582 bytes uncompressed, 1366 bytes compressed:  13.7%
```

in this line:
`-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx      208 tx defN 20-Apr-03 01:04 predefhiddenfolder/backup/WIP/32/contacts/1.vcf` it says that format is `3.0 unx`.

is there any way to zip it so format will be `0.0 fat`?

Edit: added some clarification

Edit: 
I tried using `-k` flag as sugessted by @FennecTECH

it looks better but still doesn't work.

```
$ zipinfo Backup000.NBF
Archive:  Backup000.NBF
Zip file size: 2501 bytes, number of entries: 10
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 00:37 PREDEFHI/
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 00:36 PREDEFHI/PREDEFIS/
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 00:36 PREDEFHI/PREDEFIS/USERSETT/
-rw----     2.0 fat     1160 bx defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 PREDEFHI/PREDEFIS/USERSETT/USER_SET.WBX
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 00:37 PREDEFHI/BACKUP/
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 00:37 PREDEFHI/BACKUP/WIP/
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 00:37 PREDEFHI/BACKUP/WIP/32/
drwx---     2.0 fat        0 bx stor 20-Apr-03 01:04 PREDEFHI/BACKUP/WIP/32/CONTACTS/
-rw----     2.0 fat      208 tx defN 20-Apr-03 01:04 PREDEFHI/BACKUP/WIP/32/CONTACTS/1.VCF
-rw----     2.0 fat      214 bx defN 20-Mar-30 11:31 PREDEFHI/BACKUP/WIP/F01
```

similar question that didn't solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033646/compression-method-for-xlsx-with-7z

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure this question is about Linux. Nokia phones are not Linux systems, as far as I am aware. Perhaps try on [Superuser Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: But the `zip` tool the OP uses is a Unix tool. It is a question about `zip` usage, AFAIU

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Go:

```go
package main
import (
   "archive/zip"
   "io"
   "os"
)
const creatorFAT = 0
func main() {
   // in
   file, _ := os.Open("in.txt")
   info, _ := file.Stat()
   head, _ := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
   // default is Unix
   head.CreatorVersion = creatorFAT
   // out
   zipfile, _ := os.Create("out.zip")
   archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
   // write
   writer, _ := archive.CreateHeader(head)
   io.Copy(writer, file)
   archive.Close()
}
```

Result:

```
$ zipinfo out.zip
Archive:  out.zip
Zip file size: 151 bytes, number of entries: 1
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat        7 bX stor 20-Apr-02 19:54 in.txt
1 file, 7 bytes uncompressed, 7 bytes compressed:  0.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to unzip the folder.  Then re zip it with the -k option This will get you 2.0 fat.  I don't know if this will work but its worth a try. You will need to do it with the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the user_settings.wbxml file
Certain things are supposed to be updated there, probably according to the size of the file or the number of contacts

Answer (score 0):

Let me present my powerful tool that does this automagically
https://github.com/pas-calc/nokia-contacts

You might adjust this script to your needs. For python related, you shall stick to `from zipfile import ZipFile`.